# Papervision problem with UV mapping on DAE/COLLADA model

Tags: flash, papervision3d, collada, pv3d

In PaperVision3D I am loading a COLLADA model which I have  UV mapped.  Everything seems to work okay except I am getting some bad texture distortion.  Can anyone advise me on what I am seeing and what a possible solution is?  I have attached an image of the distortion, I have tinted the obvious distortions on the right in red.

http://bandcamp.fieldsofnoise.org/dump/dae-pv3d-texture-problem.png

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Insufficient triangles, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a CompositeMaterial for debugging. Just mix your BitmapMaterial with a WireMaterial. It's just the way Papervision deals with texture distorsion. That might be corrected, since Flash Player 10 can help with that, but I'm not sure if it's implemented.

Once option would be to turn the **precise** property to true:

e.g.

```
myBitmapMaterial.precise = true;
```

but that has a cost in performance. It seems like you need to find the right ballance between quality and speed.

Another approach would be to adjust your mesh. Just for the area where the lines part of the texture would go, subdivide a few more triangles, just for that area.

HTH